# MySQL if column is reevaluated with CASE statement and then aliased the same name, how to refer to alias?

Tags: mysql

I am evaluating column with CASE statement and then aliasing it the same name as column. How do I then force MySQL to select reevaluated values and not the original?

```
SELECT
store,
CASE 
        WHEN offer IN ("offer 1", "offer 2") THEN "books"
        ELSE offer
END AS offer,

DATE(datetime) as date,

concat(COALESCE(store, ""), COALESCE((select offer)," ")) as connector

FROM sales_1 ORDER BY datetime DESC
```

In the code above, the "concat" function uses the original "offer" values and not the ones I changed in CASE statement.
I know that I could do another CASE in COALESCE(...), but there must be an easier way.

Comment: Have you tried rename calculated offer column, and this renamed column put into concat function?

Comment: The problem is at `COALESCE((select offer)`. You are selecting the column offer from no table. That is syntaxically incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is at `COALESCE((select offer)`. You are selecting the column offer from no table. That is syntaxically incorrect.

You already propose one method to achieve the expected result. Another approach will be to use subqueries as shown below.

```
SELECT
    A.store,
    A.offer,
    A.`date`
    CONCAT(COALESCE(store, ""), COALESCE(A.offer," ")) AS connector
FROM
    (SELECT
       DISTINCT
       store,
       CASE WHEN offer IN ("offer 1", "offer 2") THEN "books"
            ELSE offer
       END AS offer,
       DATE(datetime) AS `date`
    FROM sales_1 
    ORDER BY `datetime` DESC) A;
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. That gets the desired result, but it’s not really what I’m looking for. My queries are really long and this way becomes super cumbersome and I hoped that there is a better way...

Comment: I don’t think there is a problem with ‘(select offer)’. I mean I can rename statement to ‘CASE ... END as offer2’ and then use COALESCE ((select offer2) , “ “). That works perfect. I just don’t ubderstand why query does not select the evaluated column if it’s ubder the same name